# how to make values to sit on grid table using prime ng in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I have a data table and I had given static data so it was working fine. But I want data of `var e` to sit in data table. I am not getting how to make those values to fetch there.

I am getting this value in UI

```
this.List = [{
      "userId":'1',"deviceName":"System 1","deviceos":"palm OS","location":"c/ProgramFiles","browser":"Google Chrome","IsActive":"active"},
]
```

But need this value to be there

```
var e = module.init();
   console.log(e);
```

Please find working demo here [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8thvaw?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your `demo`, I made some changes and here is the required solution:

```
      var e = module.init();
   console.log(e);
   var object = {
      "userId":'1',"deviceName":this.isDeviceType,"deviceos":e.os.name,"location":this.myLocation.coords.latitude+this.myLocation.coords.longitude,"browser":e.browser.name,"IsActive":"active"};
    this.List = [object]
      })

  }
```

[**Here is a working DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kugwzt?file=src/app/app.component.ts)